# asp.net multi checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

I have an asp.net multicheckbox list with `autopostback = false`. If I check on any item it will affect the first item on the list. FI if I check on the third item, the first one will get checked as well, if then I check on the next item, the first one will get unchecked and so on is there anyway to stop this behavior.
This is my code:

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList RepeatColumns="3" ID="chkTags"  DataTextField="DisplayName" DataValueField="ID" runat="server" />
```

screencast here http://screencast.com/t/ipZ0RpOiHxhD

Comment: how about showing some real code on what's going on in your codebehind file.

Comment: Do you have any javascript associated with this list? Can you share it?

Comment: you need to look at `ListItems` in a foreach loop you can do something like the following `foreach (ListItem item in chkTags.Items){}`then check if the item is checked or not or you can check it or uncheck it

Comment: The behavior is happening on client side, and I don't have any js associated with this list other than the js asp.net generates. On the code behind everything behaves well when submitting and checking for selected items.